# Dot-and-whisker coefficient plots using only mean and 95% confidence interval estimates (not the data that produced them)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this:

```
workday <- data.frame(Measure = c("A", "A", "A"),
                      Session = c("Welcome", "Class 1", "Lunch Talk"),
                      Mean  = c(7.10, 8.90, 4.47),
                      Ci95  = c(0.40, 0.56, 0.33))
```

I need to create a coefficient plot similar to [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dotwhisker/vignettes/dotwhisker-vignette.html) from the package `dwplot`, where y-axis represents different categorical values of `Session`. The estimated mean should be a point, and the lower and upper 95% confidence intervals should be plotted as a horizontal line running through its corresponding mean.

I don't have the raw data used to produce the estimated mean (`Mean`) and 95% confidence intervals (`Ci95`) - just the values themselves, as seen in `workday`. This is equivalent to a `dwplot()` with an argument `position = identity` from `ggplot2`.

I can get here:

```
workday %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Mean, y=Session)) + 
  geom_point(position="identity") +
  ggtitle("A")
```

[image]

But it obviously does not include the horizontal confidence interval line I need.

How can I use `ggplot2` (or `dwplot`) to produce the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
workday %>%
  mutate(Low=Mean-Ci95,High=Mean+Ci95) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Session, y=Mean)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Low,ymax=High),width=0)+
  ggtitle("A")+
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]