# Create a Dot-Whisker plot in R for means/CIs of multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm currently looking to summarize my data visually in a Dot-Whisker plot using ggplot. Ideally, I'd create something that looks identical to what @Duck is able to produce in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268001/dot-and-whisker-coefficient-plots-using-only-mean-and-95-confidence-interval-es), where I'm plotting multiple variables. However, I'd like to plot the results of each variable by a separate factor variable. When I go to actually plot the figure, I receive the following error message:

```
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do. First, I load in some toy data. Then I calculate the  mean, as well as upper and lower CI bounds by each factor for the first variable. Then I repeat the process for the second variable, prior to row-binding my data frames together. Finally, I plot the data and receive the error message above.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(minority = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.8, 0.7, 0.65),
                       policy = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                       county = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))

data_shell <- data.frame(data$county) 
data_shell <- as.list(unique(data_shell$data.county)) 
data_shell <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, data_shell) # Turn list into 2 x 1 data frame

data_shell <- plyr::rename(data_shell, c("c.0..1." = "County")) # renaming column
data_shell$County <- factor(data_shell$County, levels = c(1, 0), labels = c("Yes","No")) # Labelling values

# Minority %
dw_data1 <- data_shell
dw_data1$mean <- with(data, tapply(minority, county, mean)) 
dw_data1$ci95 <- with(data, tapply(minority, county, t.test)) 
dw_data1$ci95 <- lapply(dw_data1$ci95, `[[`, 4) 
dw_data1$ci_low <- lapply(dw_data1$ci95, `[[`, 1) 
dw_data1$ci_high <- lapply(dw_data1$ci95, `[[`, 2) 

dw_data1 <- select(dw_data1, -c(ci95)) 
dw_data1$variable <- "Minority %" 

# Policy Passage
dw_data2 <- data_shell
dw_data2$mean <- with(data, tapply(policy, county, mean)) 
dw_data2$ci95 <- with(data, tapply(policy, county, t.test)) 
dw_data2$ci95 <- lapply(dw_data2$ci95, `[[`, 4) 
dw_data2$ci_low <- lapply(dw_data2$ci95, `[[`, 1) 
dw_data2$ci_high <- lapply(dw_data2$ci95, `[[`, 2) 

dw_data2 <- select(dw_data2, -c(ci95)) 
dw_data2$variable <- "Policy Passage" 

dw_append <- as.data.frame(rbind(dw_data1, dw_data2)) # appending data together

################################################################################
#                         Creating Dot-Whisker plot                            #
################################################################################

dw_plot <- dw_append %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=variable, y=mean, fill=County)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ci_low, ymax=ci_high),width=0)+
  ggtitle("A")+
  coord_flip()

dw_plot
```

I've tried re-saving as a data frame before plotting, to no avail. Any thoughts what could be driving that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have kept `ci_low` and `ci_high` as list when you used `lapply`. You can avoid this in future and keep it as a vector using `sapply` instead.

```
str(dw_append)

'data.frame':   4 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ County  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 2 1 2 1
 $ mean    : num  0.55 0.29 0.2 0.4
 $ ci_low  :List of 4
  ..$ 0: num 0.318
  ..$ 1: num -0.0397
  ..$ 0: num -0.355
  ..$ 1: num -0.28
 $ ci_high :List of 4
  ..$ 0: num 0.782
  ..$ 1: num 0.62
  ..$ 0: num 0.755
  ..$ 1: num 1.08
 $ variable: chr  "Minority %" "Minority %" "Policy Passage" "Policy Passage"
```

To fix this, you can just unlist `ci_low` and `ci_high`. That way your code will run.

```
dw_append$ci_low <- unlist(dw_append$ci_low) 
dw_append$ci_high <- unlist(dw_append$ci_high) 

dw_plot <- dw_append %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=variable, y=mean, fill=County)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ci_low, ymax=ci_high),width=0)+
    ggtitle("A")+
    coord_flip()
```

[image]